# Meaning of "~" beore plaform version in Cordova

Tags: cordova

I'm just new in Cordova and I need a little help to understand something.

When I type $ cordova platform list, it returns the following :

Installed platforms :

Available platforms :

android ~6.2.2

blackberry10 ~3.8.0

browser ~4.1.0

webos ~3.7.0

windows ~5.0.0

I would like to know precisely the meaning of " ~ " before a platform version. Does it mean that all the previous versions are supported ? Or just the mentionned version ? Also, I don't see neither iPhone nor iPad platforms in this list. Does it mean they are'nt supported ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cordova uses semver for the versions

That means the versions are semantic

In a version like x.y.z

- x is incremented after a mayor change
- y is incremented after a minor change
- z is incremented after a patch change

the tilde (~) allows newer patch level versions

So, if you have android ~6.2.2, and 6.2.3 comes out, you'll get it, but if 6.3.0 comes out, you won't.

If you want to get minor changes too, you can use the caret (^) instead

[More info here](https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/)

Comment: Good explanation